# How can I get the values from an Array in a JSON object using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, json

Here is the JSON object:

```
{
  'id' => 'itemGuitar',
  'description' => 'Pete Townshend once played this guitar while his own axe was in the shop having bits of drumkit removed from it.',
  'price' => 5695.99,
  'urls' => array('http://www.thewho.com/',
                  'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pete_Townshend')
}
```

Here is my getJSON code:

```
$.getJSON("getDetailsJSON.php?ImageID=" + escape(itemName), function (json) {
         var info = "<p>id: " + json["id"] + "</p>" +
             "<p>description: " + json["description"] + "</p>" +
             "<p>price: $" + json["price"] + "</p>" +
             "<p>urls:</p><ul>";
        $.each(json["urls"], function (i) {
             info += "<li><a href='" + this[i] + "'>" + this[i] + "</a></li>";
        });
        info += "</ul>";
        $("#description").append(info);
 });
```

Specifically looking at:

```
$.each(json["urls"], function (i) {
     info += "<li><a href='" + this[i] + "'>" + this[i] + "</a></li>";
});
```

My problem is that the valules in the "urls" loop are not correct. I am gettting https in list form a single letter at a time instead of each list element containing the full address.

Comment: Try using `this` instead of `this[i]`.

Comment: Small nitpick. `=>` isn't the key value separator in json.  same thing with `array()`

Comment: @Taplar that code looks to be on the server side and in php.

Comment: So it is **not** JSON, :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [jQuery documentation for each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

> In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time. (**The value can also be accessed through the `this` keyword**, but Javascript will always wrap the `this` value as an `Object` even if it is a simple string or number value.)

So in your code `i` is the index of the current element in the iteration and `this` is the current url.

```
$.each(json["urls"], function (i) {
     info += "<li><a href='" + this + "'>" + this + "</a></li>";
});
```

or even better, use a value parameter explicitly

```
$.each(json["urls"], function (i, url) {
     info += "<li><a href='" + url + "'>" + url + "</a></li>";
});
```